# Trouble getting value from stored procedure temp table column using cursor

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

First I know that using a cursor is not the best way of doing this but the IT manager is an old SQL person and that is the way he wants it done, otherwise I wouldn't be doing it this way.

I am using a stored procedure that does among other things create a temp table and try to fill it with data from another table that has been concatenated in the stored procedure. I can not seem to get the problem description, the field that needs to be concatenated, to update correctly. Actually not all.

Here is the part of the stored procedure that builds the temp table and tries to update it.

```
--Build problem entry
Create Table ##tmp_problem
(
    prbqarnum varchar(7),
    prbdesc varchar(max)
)

--Dump problem(s) into tbl based on qar#
Insert Into ##tmp_problem(prbqarnum) Select qarnum From tbl_qarbase Where currstatus = @qarstatus

--Declare tbl cursor
Declare tbl_Cursor CURSOR For
Select tbl_problems.qarnum, tbl_problems.problemdesc
From tbl_problems
Join tbl_qarbase On tbl_problems.qarnum = tbl_qarbase.qarnum
Where tbl_qarbase.currstatus = @qarstatus

--Open the tbl cursor
Open tbl_Cursor

--Fetch first row of data
Fetch next From tbl_Cursor Into @qarparm, @desc

--Declare temp problem desc variable
Declare @tmpproblem varchar(max)


--Loop to get problem data
While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    Begin

        Set @tmpproblem = (Select prbdesc From ##tmp_problem Where prbqarnum = @qarparm) + '   ' + @desc

        Update ##tmp_problem Set prbdesc = @tmpproblem
        --Get Next Row of Data
        Fetch next From tbl_Cursor Into @qarparm, @desc
    End

--Close tbl cursor
Close tbl_Cursor
--Deallocate tbl cursor
Deallocate tbl_Cursor
```

I know that the temp table is working because after the procedure runs i am able to query the temp table and see that the qarnum's are being put in.

What isn't happening is that there is a description field, that may have anywhere from one to N lines, and based on the qar # I need to concatenate the descriptions into one string and then insert it into the temp table, which isn't happening.

Here is a picture on the queries out puts. The top is the temp table and the bottom is the table that the cursor is built on.

[image]

So the question is, besides using a cursor, what i am doing wrong?? I have been Googling for several hours but nothing seems to work.

One last note: I am not seeing any errors anywhere.

Comment: You pretty much nailed it. Using a cursor is the biggest issue I see there. Followed closely by using a global temp table. Also your update statement is updating the entire global temp each iteration because you have no where clause. This should be a single update statement and this whole thing fixes itself.

Comment: I am going to switch it back to a local temp table. I was just seeing that made a difference. As for the where clause that might it. thanks for the look..

Comment: But really the cursor is not the right tool for this. It should be a single update statement. Doing this in a cursor is a bad approach, unless you are doing this just for fun.

Comment: The more I look at this the more I shake my head in wonderment. Why not just populate your temp table the same time you populate the first column?

Comment: why not just `Update ##tmp_problem Set prbdesc = @tmpproblem WHERE prbqarnum = @qarparm`? not sure if `Set @tmpproblem...` is necessary here.

Comment: The problem is that there could one line of problem description per qarnum or there could 10 or more. I need the problem description to concatenate into one string...

Comment: Seeing your last comment you could still use the basic concept I posted. But instead of a basic select statement you would want to utilize STUFF and FOR XML to generate the concatenated values.

Answer (score 1):

You could GREATLY simplify this. There is no need for an update at all. Just populate both columns in your temp table. You entire code could be reduced to this.

```
Create Table #tmp_problem
(
    prbqarnum varchar(7),
    prbdesc varchar(max)
)

--Dump problem(s) into tbl based on qar#
Insert Into #tmp_problem(prbqarnum, prbdesc) Select qarnum, problemdesc From tbl_qarbase Where currstatus = @qarstatus
```

Answer (score 0):

You should handle NULLs:

```
Set @tmpproblem = ISNULL(Select prbdesc From ##tmp_problem 
                         Where prbqarnum = @qarparm), '') + '   ' 
                  + ISNULL(@desc, '');
```

Plus you need to add some condition to `UPDATE`

```
Update ##tmp_problem Set prbdesc = @tmpproblem  -- updates entire table
--WHERE ...
```

Comment: @SeanLange Good catch